# On updating iOS app, force plist in Documents to be overwritten/deleted?

Tags: ios, plist

I guess my general question which I googled to no luck: Is there a method that is called right after an app is updated?

More details: My situation is that I have a plist in the bundle. When a user first tries to access the plist, I check the Documents directory and if it's not there, copy it from the bundle. This allows the user to overwrite with their data when necessary. However whenever I update the app, I need to have a NEW plist in the bundle which will **overwrite** the user's existing plist in the Documents directory. Obviously I only want this to happen after an app update, not just every time the app is run. Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append the bundle version (CFBundleVersion) to the plist you want updated and dynamically load a depending on the bundle version stored in the apps info.plist.

So for version 1.3, you'd load your_plist.1.3.plist

```
NSString *plistString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"your_plist_%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];

[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:plistString ofType:@"plist"];
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! Since you included code, you get the right answer selected :)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is set a key in NSUserDefaults with the app revision (some constant which you increment on every release or just the value from CFBundleVersion) currently running. When you open your app, do a quick check to see if the revision is lower than the current revision and then overwrite the plist and update the revision stored so subsequent launches of the same version do not cause an overwrite of the plist. For subsequent launches, if the revisions are the same value, move on ahead to the rest of the application

Comment: I use this approach all the time. It's a very simple and efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could also change the name of the plist in your code. That way a new plist will be copied to the documents folder. You can also add code to delete the old one :)